# How to get SwipeRefreshLayout to set text in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, swiperefreshlayout

When looking at applications such as PlayNewsstand, QuidCo, OneDrive and YahooMail when the swipe down to refresh gesture occurs, the action bar's contents are changed to indicate that the swipe down is causing a refresh. GMail however does not update the action bar contents and just relies on the progressBar to indicate the refresh.

Using the new SwipeRefreshLayout how would one update the ActionBar contents to act like apps like PlayNewsstand.

I have seen a lot of references to Chris Banes' ActionBar-PulLToRefresh which supports the ActionBar being updated, but this written prior to SwipeRefreshLayout and therefore is not an example of how to get wipeRefreshLayout to update the ActionBar text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
swipeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                Log.i("INFO", "MOVE");
                getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Swipe to refresh");
                getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
                getActivity().getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_title);
                getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

custom_title.xml - To center your text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="my Title"
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And at the end of your onRefresh or when not listening to the touch anymore set the title and logo back.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I have action bar items that I would have to hide if I want the actionbar to just contain my text but this gives me a brilliant starting place, thank you.

Comment: @user2855036, is there anyway to save the actionbar properties in an easy way before changing it, then after the refresh is done, I can set the actionbar back to the old one.

Comment: @HanHe just save the properties in local variables